# Change the maximum amount of characters in the Meta Description

Tags: php, magento, meta

I have a problem to change the limit of characters in the meta description. I\\’ve modified as shown here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/278911/#t392935

But it only detects if you create or modify the product from magento admin and I upload products from .csv file and I have to go one by one to each product in the meta description and then go down from 255 to 155.

Is there any way to change it without changing it from Magento, I think the problem comes because the code says:

setOnkeyup

Comment: what do u mean by go down from 255 to 155 in csv file ? i think database dont got any issue about character limit.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that you have too long data in your meta_description for each of products.

You can short the value before loading it by layout XML config, or directly by the PHTML template for each page type.

Better way to have result you need is NOT ti import longest data than you need.

Importing unnecessary data solving import and after that you need to correct it again.

Maybe will be better to make script to cut-out meta description in CSV file before you start import to magento.

I solved simmilar issue and make something like this:
(script take your csv file and make new with only 2 columns, SKU and updated text named DECSRIPTION, than you can import to magento after your firs import of csv (first import everything without meta description, after that ONLY your meta description cuted out by 250 chars for example))

```
//////// get csv and take variable you need in my case is it SKU
$csv = file_get_contents ('myimportfile.csv'); 

function parse_csv ($csv_string, $delimiter = ";", $skip_empty_lines = true, $trim_fields = true)
{
    $enc = preg_replace('/(?<!")""/', '!!Q!!', $csv_string);
    $enc = preg_replace_callback(
        '/"(.*?)"/s',
        function ($field) {
            return urlencode(utf8_encode($field[1]));
        },
        $enc
    );
    $lines = preg_split($skip_empty_lines ? ($trim_fields ? '/( *\R)+/s' : '/\R+/s') : '/\R/s', $enc);
    return array_map(
        function ($line) use ($delimiter, $trim_fields) {
            $fields = $trim_fields ? array_map('trim', explode($delimiter, $line)) : explode($delimiter, $line);
            return array_map(
                function ($field) {
                    return str_replace('!!Q!!', '"', utf8_decode(urldecode($field)));
                },
                $fields
            );
        },
        $lines
    );
}
// list of variables to array
$vystup = parse_csv($csv);
enter code here
```

After that you can loop each variable to row, modify by PHP what you want:

```
$seznamsku = array();
    foreach ($vystup as $row){
    array_push($seznamsku, $sku[0]);
unset($seznamsku[0]);
$seznamskufin = array_filter($seznamsku, 'strlen');
};
foreach ($seznamskufin as $row) {
    $__OUT .= '     "ROW_YOURSKU","'.htmlspecialchars(substr(ROW_YOURMETADESCRIPTION, 0, 155)).'"'."\n"; // TODO exactly dont know how to call variables, maybye $row['something'] or $row[0]['something']
    };
    $feed = fopen($newfile, 'w');
    fwrite($feed, $__OUT);
    fclose($feed);
    //remember to unset variables
```

you can get another csv file with description long 250 chars and import it to magento
(You must update code it only returns list of SKU, get your descriptions from file);

Comment: An `s` modifier on a pattern that only contains `\R` makes no sense.